# Initializing an m x n array of 0s in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a nested array of 0s of m x n dimensions. I will be iterating through the array and assigning values later.

If I do this:

```
l = [[0] * 3] * 3
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if i == 0:
            l[i][j] = 1
```

My conditional doesn't seem to apply and every value is assigned to the list regardless of i. I know the problem is caused by copying the lists of 0s in the first line of code. So I took a slice of each inner list like this to fix it:

```
l = [[0] * 3] * 3
for i in range(3):
    l[i] = l[i][:]
    for j in range(3):
        if i == 0:
            l[i][j] = 1
```

This feels redundant and I'm wondering if there's a better way to initialize nested lists.

Comment: Note if you were using `numpy` this would just be `numpy.zeros((m, n))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that lists in python are [mutable](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/) and when copying them using `*` you actually copying the reference to the same list, and not creating new lists.

```
>>> l = [[0]*3]*3
>>> l
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> l[0][0] = 1
>>> l
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

You want to make your lists different like that by creating theme separately:

```
>>> l = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]  # each list created by it own, and not as you did when it just a copy to the reference to the same list.
>>> l[0][0] = 1
>>> l
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Lists are mutable in both of your examples; the *problem* is the reference copying.

Comment: I was referring to the opening statement: *"Your issue is that lists in python are mutable"*; I wouldn't bury the actual issue in a code comment.

Comment: Got it, you're right, updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.